# How to show paste menu in BasicTextField with FocusRequester

Tags: text, android-jetpack-compose, focus

How to show paste menu in BasicTextField with FocusRequester.
I have click area (Row) with focusRequester.requestFocus().

On long click on the Row, the cursor must be set to BasicTextField and must be shown Paste menu.

```
Row(modifier = Modifier.clickable{focusRequester.requestFocus()}){
     BasicTextField(modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester), 
         decorationBox = { innerTextField ->Box(){innerTextField()}}
{}
}
```

[image]